# Smooth scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this code that I took from the internet because I haven't learned jquery and js yet. For smooth scrolling for anchors on my page and when its scrolls its just scroll all the way to the bottom of the page beacuse its not long enough yet and there are some sections that are just short.

My question is how can I set end to the scroll?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            // Prevent default anchor click behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // Store hash
            var hash = this.hash;

            // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
            // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 900, function(){

                // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } // End if
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I set end to the scroll`?

Comment: Please also include some markup. And a snippet would be nice as well.

Comment: i mean that when i click the button so it scrolls to the end of the page . and i want it to stop at a point that i decide

Comment: there is a way to tell the scroll to stop like after 100px ?